# How can I store the cypher query value into a variable inside python function?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I want to store the price average of the data that I have inside my neo4j database, so I can then use the python variable to define if the product is cheap or expensive.

I already have the cypher query which is giving me all the average prices of all services that I have in my database. Now I want to store this query result into a variable or list. So I can use it to define if the price is cheap or expensive (if price <= average) it is cheap otherwise it is expensive.

```py
      def average(self):

           query = '''
              MATCH (p:Price)-[:COSTS]-(s:Service)
              RETURN avg(toFloat(p.monthly)) AS Average, p.currency AS Currency, s.service_name AS Service
               '''
           return  graph.run(query, average= self.Average, currency= self.Currency, service_name=self.Service )
```

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your query can return multiple rows since it specifies `Currency` and `Service` as the unique grouping keys for the `AVG` [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/). So `average()` should probably return something like a list of dictionaries.

The `run()` function returns a [Cursor](https://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Cursor.data), which has a [data()](https://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Cursor.data) function that will "extract the entire result as a list of dictionaries".

So, this version of `average()` should return a list of dictionaries for the query results:

```
  def average(self):
       query = '''
          MATCH (p:Price)-[:COSTS]-(s:Service)
          RETURN avg(toFloat(p.monthly)) AS Average, p.currency AS Currency, s.service_name AS Service
           '''
       return graph.run(query).data()
```